How to change io.micronaut log level?
I have a Java 17 Gradle application and use JUnit Jupiter for testing. When I run tests io.micronaut diligently writes all its numerous DEBUG log messages. I want to change the vebosity level and after consulting the documentation I tried to change the appropriate values in application.yml and log4j2.xml in both main and test folder without avail. I also tried to change log level on runtime, also without avail.
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    final Logger logger = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);


Please explain why downvote?

The problem is that the original author of the project has inadvertently copy-pasted from another project libraries into the build.gradle file, so that it has both log4j and logback definitions.
implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api")
implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.6")
implementation platform("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-bom:2.20.0")
runtimeOnly("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core")
runtimeOnly("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl")

and used log4j2.xml whereas the system internally has used logback and therefore all my changes had no effect. deleting all log4j files and using logback.xml works perfectly.

You can change the logging level in application configuration file. For tests it is usually application-test.yaml file located in src/test/resources. And add there the logger definition you need, for example:
logger:
  levels:
    io.micronaut: OFF

And you can also have different levels for different packages:
logger:
  levels:
    io.micronaut.http: ERROR
    io.micronaut.security: INFO

If you use properties file or different format other than yaml, then change the definition accordingly.

I tested it, in my project the file application-test.yaml is not even recognized. Setting io.micronaut: OFF in both application.yml files (main and test) has no effect

Which version of Micronaut do you have?

micronautVersion=4.3.4
